# В чем литературная ценность обериутов?

Tags: литература, поэзия

Помню, в школе был очень удивлен, когда впервые прочитал стихи обериутов, в частности, Введенского. Нечто вроде (привожу по памяти, поэтому могу ошибиться):
*Я выхожу из кабака,

Там мертвый труп вещут пока,

А труп моей жены родной

Вон там, за гробовой стеной.

Я горько плачу, страшно злюсь,

О гроб главою колочусь

И вынимаю потроха,

Чтоб показать, что в них уха.*

Мы с друзьями в школе писали такие стишки просто для смеха и, конечно, не претендовали на какую-то литературную ценность - посмеялись и забыли. Тут же целое литературное общество, стихи печатают в журналах. Я чего-то не понимаю в поэзии?))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, не печатают,  а печатали в 20-е годы 20 столетия. Это была литературная молодёжь , ищущая новые формы, предшественники современной поэзии абсурда.Алогичность Хармса и «бессмыслица» Введенского были призваны демонстрировать, что только абсурд передает бессвязность жизни и смерти в постоянно меняющемся пространстве и времени. Проводимые в стране новой властью абсурдные социальные преобразования, современниками которых оказались обэриуты, подтверждали актуальность их художественно-философских установок.

Во-вторых,"ценность" их творчества в своё время оценена властными структурами как антисоветская: всё непонятное было всегда враждебно. Судьба всех участников группы была на редкость печальной: арестованы были почти все, одни расстреляны, другие прошли через лагеря, третьи были репрессированы, погибли в заключении.

В-третьих,  ценность всё же есть. Д.Хармс, например,создатель юмора нового типа в детской поэзии.Необычный поэт, надевший маску чудака, иностранца, жил на границах искусства и жизни, превращая свою жизнь в Игру, Театр, Зрелище….В отличие от взрослых, дети сразу поняли и приняли Хармса, и уже на Первом всесоюзном съезде писателей в 1934 году в выступлении Л. Кассиля были подчеркнуты яркие удачи Хармса, Введенского и Заболоцкого в литературе для дошкольников. 
В детской поэзии обэриуты создали новое направление, которое мы назовем парадоксально-игровой поэзией. Оно сосуществовало с традиционными, уже установившимися направлениями: сказочным юмором К. Чуковского, детской сатирой С. Маршака, А. Барто, С. Михалкова.

Великолепными примерами юмора нового типа являются "Лошадка", "Кто?" А. Введенского, "Что такое а ля брасс?", "Мистер Кук Барла Барла" Н. Заболоцкого, "Евсей", "Барабан", "Оркестр" Ю. Владимирова и др.

Широко образованный человек, владеющий несколькими языками, Хармс очень любил парадоксально-фантастическую книгу Л. Кэррола "Алиса в стране чудес". Но особое отношение у Хармса к философии и поэзии Велемира Хлебникова. Многие хлебниковские черты отразились в произведениях Хармса: свежий, открытый взгляд на мир ("голыми глазами" - Декларация ОБЭРИУ).

В стихах Хармса крутится забавный абсурдный мир, где все наоборот: кашу не ели, а пили, шли задом наперёд, а непонятное нечто «чирикало любезно…Юрий Владимиров продемонстрировал чудеса стихотворства в небольшом стихотворении «Барабан», употребив сорок пять однокоренных слов. Текст буквально громыхает барабанным громом. Цель виртуоза — передать текучесть звуков, образующих речь.Стихи обэриутов, в особенности детские, представляют собой разные игры.

Мне, например,из них самый близкий Н Заболоцкий.

В глуши бутылочного рая,

Где пальмы высохли давно,

Под электричеством играя,

В бокале плавало окно.

Оно, как золото, блестело,

Потом садилось, тяжелело,

Над ним пивной дымок вился...

Но это рассказать нельзя.

(«Вечерний бар» Заболоцкого, 1926 г.)

Есть лица, подобные пышным порталам,

Где всюду великое чудится в малом.

Есть лица—подобия жалких лачуг,

Где варится печень и мокнет сычуг.

Иные холодные, мертвые лица

Закрыты решетками, словно темница.

Другие — как башни, в которых давно

Никто не живет и не смотрит в окно.

Но малую хижинку знал я когда-то,

Была неказиста она, небогата,

Зато из окошка ее на меня

Струилось дыханье весеннего дня.

Поистине мир и велик и чудесен!

Есть лица—подобья ликующих песен.

Из этих, как солнце, сияющих нот

Составлена песня небесных высот

А вот ещё:

Прямые лысые мужья

Сидят, как выстрел из ружья...

Можно почитать о них:

http://www.webmechta.com/history/1440-oberiuti

http://shpori-vsem.ru/literature/86-detliteratura.html?start=12

Comment: И сейчас печатают. Я, например, познакомилась с обериутами, благодаря одному из толстых литературных журналов, что вроде "Невы".

Comment: Восхитительно!)))

Answer (score 0):

Да, у Заболоцкого много хороших стихов есть. Со школьной скамьи ( он был единственным, который был включен в программу) мне запомнился только этот стих.

Клялась ты - до гроба
Быть милой моей.
Опомнившись, оба
Мы стали умней.

Опомнившись, оба
Мы поняли вдруг,
Что счастья до гроба
Не будет, мой друг.

Колеблется лебедь
На пламени вод.
Однако к земле ведь
И он уплывет.

И вновь одиноко
Заблещет вода,
И глянет ей в око
Ночная звезда.

Comment: Кстати, второй стих Заболоцкого( который привела Людмила) напоминает английский стих " Дом, который построил Джек".